# Why ',' or ')' expected in my code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I get error:

> ',' or ')' expected

[image]

My MonitorQueryWsImpl :

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.cinsoft.smart3.monitor.ws.MonitorQueryWs",targetNamespace = "http://ws.monitor.smart3.cinsoft.com/")
public class MonitorQueryWsImpl implements MonitorQueryWs {

    @Autowired
    private MonitorQueryService monitorQueryService;

    /**
     * 监控滚动信息接口 (I_D_TraceFlowInfo)
     *
     * @param projectNo  项目编号
     * @param areaNo     行政区划编号字符串
     * @param secrectKey 密钥
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public String traceFlowInfo(String projectNo, String areaNo, String secrectKey) {

        return monitorQueryService.traceFlowInfo(String projectNo, String areaNo, String secrectKey);  // Here I got the error.
    }
}
```

In my MonitorQueryService:

```
public interface MonitorQueryService extends BaseService {

    /**
     * 监控滚动信息接口 (I_D_TraceFlowInfo)
     *
     * @param projectNo  项目编号
     * @param areaNo     行政区划编号字符串
     * @param secrectKey 密钥
     * @return
     */
    public String traceFlowInfo(String projectNo, String areaNo, String secrectKey);
}
```

So, I think my code is no mistake, but why I get the error, strange?

Comment: If you call a method you do not have to specify the Parameter type. `return monitorQueryService.traceFlowInfo(projectNo, areaNo,  secrectKey);  // Here I got the error.
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call methods with types, just variables

```
return monitorQueryService.traceFlowInfo(projectNo, areaNo, secrectKey);
```

Comment: upvoted for being the first - I don't think we need 4 or more duplicate answers

Comment: Oh, my low grade error, no.

Comment: @eis I agree, few seconds made the difference in the case of identical answers